# How friendly or hostile are creatures summoned by a Wild Magic Surge likely to be?

Tags: dnd-5e, sorcerer, summoning, wild-magic

A Wild Magic Surge has a 6% chance to summon one or more creatures. They are all lawful good or lawful neutral: Unicorn, Flumph, Modron. Thus I would imagine that being summoned by a chaotic event doesn't necessarily predispose them to help the sorcerer. On the other hand I don't see a lawful good creature attack the sorcerer for no other reason than having been summoned either.

Other than "DM's discretion", has there been any comment from the developers on how these creatures are likely to react to being summoned? As that is most likely to happen in combat, would they be more likely to fight for or against the group? Or would they just stand around and do nothing?

Comment: Related: [Which summoning spells conjure willing creatures, and which unwilling?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/100151/which-summoning-spells-conjure-willing-creatures-and-which-unwilling)

Comment: [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/100151/which-summoning-spells-conjure-willing-creatures-and-which-unwilling) does not answer what happens on a Wild Surge though.

Comment: @ShadowKras Right, it's just related

Comment: @markovchain [designer-reasons] doesn't appear to fit here. “What is the intended rule” doesn't have anything to do with *reasons*, if you see what I mean. That tag was created less for adding to every “how is this rule intended to work” question (which would make it pretty useless for searching), but rather for that specific kind of “why did the designers make design choice *X*” question that we often get. E.g., it would fit here if the Q was instead “Have the designers said why they put Flumphs on the list?” or something.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I've rolled back the edit, you're right. Thanks for the catch :)

Comment: I'm not sure the "summoning" tag is relevant. Per Wild Magic, the creatures are not actually Summoned or Conjured.

Answer (score 8):

From a developer standpoint, I can't comment, since I'm not a developer.

However, if you think about it, these creatures pop into existence, more than likely in a scene of chaos. One of two things will happen, as in any situation of immediate reaction: fight or flight.

Now trying to figure out what these individual creatures are going to do, in each particular combat, is pretty widespread, and far too broad to come up with a definitive answer, so let's take the average "DM's discretion" situation as an example (and use one of my own personal experiences as well).

> ***POOF!*** In the middle of a turmoil, a dark, dingy dungeon, full of orcs and goblins, a unicorn appears. Naturally, this completely random occurrence is going to confuse everybody, probably enough to stop the fight for a second. The unicorn, on the other hand, was just spending its evening getting ready for bed, and suddenly it's in this foul place!? How? Why? It's confused, and it's going to react.
>
> Now, it sees two things: Orcs, and a group of people, mismatched but clearly not part of the orc horde. And one of them is hurt. As a creature of pure spirit, it would more than likely try to help those in pain rather than cause pain itself, so it opts to heal the injured man, then ***POOF!*** it once again vanishes, leaving a rather confused group of companions and orcs standing around, wondering what the hell just happened, until the barbarian realises he's still raging.

True, in this situation, a confused beast would likely react violently, charging at the first thing it sees, but not all creatures are dumb animals looking to shed blood. In these situations, they can either, stop, think, evaluate and react accordingly, or simply react out of fear and confusion, as is the same for any creature, person or deity in the D&D universe.

Comment: Please note, regarding the example, that the summoning lasts for 1 minute for both unicorns and modrons. (The unicorn *could* teleport a mile away, though.)

Answer (score 3):

## Conjure (summoning) Spells vs Wild Magic

Conjure spells carry specific language around how the creature responds to you within their descriptions (and those vary by spell/creature).

Wild Magic does not have those descriptions, but instead says (PHB104):

> Controlled by the DM

If you're looking for guidance as a DM, it is entirely within your purview as to how you want those creatures (modron, unicorn) to respond to the situation that they have arrived in.

### What just happened?!

Unfortunately, there is no specific guidance on how a Modron or Unicorn will react, but you can read up on their Monster Manual entries (MM 224 for Modrons and MM294 for Unicorns) and consider what's happening in the environment at the time of the surge.

Play them as you would any creature randomly entering the environment. They have no knowledge of how they got there, so have some fun with it :)